# Is it possible to add assemblies Oracle.DataAccess.dll manualy to visual studio 2012 Ultimate

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I need to add the reference  `System.Oracle.DataAccess.Client;`but because I cant find it in my reference list I though the possibility of adding it manually. is it possible? thank you for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can manually add your reference by right-clicking on your project's "References" in Solution Explorer, choosing "Add Reference" from the context-sensitive menu that appears. The "Reference Manager" dialog box will open.  In the Reference Manager dialog box, click the "Browse..." button at the bottom.  This will open the "Select the files to reference..." dialog.  Surf to your desired assembly, choose it, and press "Add". Press "OK" until you're out and you should be good to go.

Comment: I did that but couldn't find anything. What I meant by manually is typing directly the code in the config page.

Comment: When you say you couldn't find anything, are you saying that you can't find the assembly containing `System.Oracle.DataAccess.Client` on your system?

Comment: yes that's what I meant, I search in the reference list and I also browse but nothing found. All what I found for oracle using System.Data.OracleClient; which I'm already using it

Comment: Please see @user2887640 's solution above. He is correct - the assembly you seek is not named `System.Oracle.DataAccess.Client`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such namespace called "System.Oracle.DataAccess.Client". There is "Oracle.DataAccess.Client" which is part of the "Oracle.DataAccess.dll" assembly. This comes with the ODP.Net. You will have to setup ODP.Net (or ODAC components) in your development machine to be able to view this assembly in the Visual Studio Add Reference dialog